# How can I edit my code while debugging using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

How can I change my code while debugging it so when it breaks I'll see the original code?

I have a program that runs for hours or days, and I want to debug it. Meanwhile instead of waiting I want to keep working on it's code.
But if I change the code I can't break my running session and see it's original code.

EDIT:
I disabled the "Edit and Continue" feature in order to do so, because when it's enabled and the debugger is on, my solution gets "locked" and can't be changed.

Comment: `CTRL+C` `CTRL+V` your project + open another window of vs + run it there and continue working in the copied one, once you finish you repeat the process ;)

Comment: which Framework/version are you using?

Comment: .net4.5 visual studio 2013

Comment: Right now im doing exactly that, with 2 VS's open. But it's alot of trouble and I figured there must be a better way.

Comment: How about logging...

Comment: What do you mean? Mikko

Comment: What @chouaib says is probably the better solution. Your code should be under source control anyway so just clone your repository elsewhere and work on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two copies of your solution:

- one to keep working on it
- other with the original code, as it was when you started debugging your application

Now open two instances of Visual Studio:

- other copy to keep working on it
- one with the original source code, and attached to the debugged process

You can safely have the "edit and continue" option enabled in your debugging instance, and use this functionality there - i.e. you can try a change in the original source code to see if it works as expected, and then apply the same change in the working copy of your solution.

This is the only way to do it. If you don't have the original source code apart, the debugger has no way to show you the original source code.

Note: you can open a new instance of VS with the original source code, and attach to the running process, and then detach from the process and close VS without interfering with the running application. See the options "Attach to process..." and "Detach all" of the "Debug" menu.

Comment: That's pretty much how I do it right now, but that's alot of trouble making copies of my solution and working with 2 VS at the same time. I was hoping there is a built in solution in VS for that case since it seems to be pretty common case. Anyway thanks, I'll do it that way.